# Add UV water purifier to dishwasher/disposal circuit using switch/outlet combo?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, circuit, water-filtration

So, I've got a dishwasher and a switched garbage disposal on the same 20a circuit. I am looking to add a DC plugged UV water filter by swapping out the current handy box switch with a GFCI switch/outlet combo. Thus, maintaining the switch ability of the disposal, passing through power to the dishwasher, and allowing for an outlet for the UV filter.

As with most posts I've read, I am looking to see if this is a feasible approach or if I'm an idiot, haha.

Thanks so much in advance for all the help!

Please see below for some details:

- Dishwasher: 7.74 amps
- Disposal: 5.6 amps | 1hp
- UV Filter: 0.5 amps
- State: Georgia
- Switch/Outlet Combo: [Amazon Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B017KUEWCO)
- Under Sink Image: [image]

Comment: a) Can't tell from the picture but it looks like your dishwasher drain hose is not making a high loop - it needs to do that, unless you have a traditional air gap; b) You can't have general purpose receptacles on a circuit that has >50% hardwired loads - 7+5 > 10 (20/2), so that's technically not allowed. If you can hardwire the UV then it would be OK (all 3 together well under 16 (80% of 20)). But while you're working on things, you may want to consider rewiring so that the switch can be above the counter so you can see what you are doing when you turn on the disposal.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact   The only way I can think of off hand to hardwired it is to use a similar matched transformer(like a door bell transformer)  for the UV light or get a 2 amp(max) 120v UV light.

Comment: Is the dishwasher and disposal cord-and-plug connected?

Comment: Is the switch intended to control the GD?

Comment: Hey crew,

Thanks so much for the responses! Replies below:


manassehkatz - Yeah, i've got all kinds of things I need fixed up over here. Unfortunately, I bought it this way, haha. Agreed on the technically not allowed front, and I can look into a hardwire solution given the current wiring. If I were to get that circuit below 50% (remove the dishwasher or something), then does this become more feasible? 

crip659 - Interesting thought! Could definitely do some splicing.

Harper - They are all part of the same hard-wired circuit.

@Huesmann - Yeah, that's the idea currently.

Comment: Can you post the make/model of your UV purifier, or a link to the instruction manual for that matter, @VonBaaron?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - Absolutely! Here you are: https://www.waterdropfilter.com/collections/ro-parts-accessories/products/uv-water-sterilizer